# How to create a github pull request from a forked repository back to the original repository using the github API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-cli

In git/github I want to propose a change to a single file.

To do so, I

- fork the repository
- clone the repository locally
- make the changes and the commit on a new feature branch
- push the feature branch to my forked repo
- create and merge a pull request to merge the changes from the feature branch to master

Now how can I programatically (via API) create a new pull request to merge the changes I have put in the forked repo to the original repo? How to do that?

The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request) only seems to handle the case when it is the same repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation can be confusing. The following request will create a new pull request on *`FORKOWNER/THEREPO`* to merge *`FORKER:newbranch`* into *`FORKOWNER:main`*:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/FORKOWNER/THEREPO/pulls \
  -d '{"title":"XYZ", "body":"ABC", "head":"FORKER:newbranch", "base":"main"}'
```

This can also be done with the [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) command of the GitHub CLI:

```sh
gh api --method POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  repos/FORKOWNER/THEREPO/pulls \
  -f title='XYZ' -f body='ABC' -f head='FORKER:newbranch' -f base='main'
```

Or directly with the [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) command of the GitHub CLI:

```sh
gh pr create --repo FORKOWNER/THEREPO \
  --title "XYZ" --body "ABC" --head FORKER:newbranch --base main
```